# Is it possible to use compiler directives in quotations?

Tags: delphi

Let's say I have this code

```
ShowMessage( {$I test.inc} );
```

If I create the file `test.inc` with content `'hello'` and I execute the code I get a message saying `hello` and it's OK. But I don't want to write quotations in the included file and do something like this:

```
ShowMessage('{$I test.inc}');
```

and then write a simple `hello` in `test.inc`. That means that I'm looking to write compiler directives in the midst of string. Is it possible?

Comment: This is the classic XY problem

Comment: Judging by the answer given, I think including the ' in the txt file might be the best solution

Comment: @TobyAllen: That text file is supposed to be a standard XML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One dirty way to do this would be:

```
ShowMessage({$I Quote.inc}{$I test.inc}{$I Quote.inc});
```

I hope others have better solutions.

Comment: I think this is the only way you could do it.

Comment: Given the restrictions of the question, this is the only solution. If you post another question in which you describe the underlying problem, you might get more suitable suggestions. (For instance, your example here has your include file with just 5 characters, which hardly seems worth the trouble. If your real problem has much larger runs of text, then you might want to embed the text in a *resource*. That's not an answer to the question you posed here, though, because it's not using a compiler directive to include a string literal.)

Comment: I'll post a specific question for that. Thank you for your time.